# How to Concatenate multiple columns at once?

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, concatenation

I have an excel sheet as follows:

```
A   B   D       D       E
157 158 14644   28495   Https://www.google.com\
110 111 10142   21123   Https://www.youtube.com\
192 193 18538   36658   Https://www.baidu.com\
164 165 15471   29028   Https://www.qq.com\
100 101 9135    19531   Https://www.facebook.com\
155 156 15153   27725   Https://www.sohu.com\
89  90  8489    16273   Https://www.360.cn\
21  22  2004    4269    Https://www,yahoo.com\
67  68  6373    12604   Https://www.amazon.com\
101 102 9475    17490   Https://www.wikipedia.org\
```

I want to concentrate them so that I get:

```
A    
157,158,14644,28495,Https://www.google.com\


110,111,10142,21123,Https://www.youtube.com\
```

.
.
.
and so on.

Is there any way I can do this in one fell swoop?

Comment: If you have Office 365, use TEXTJOIN and copy the formula down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Excel's *concatenate* formula to achieve that for one row, then copy the formula down.
`=CONCATENATE(A2,",",B2,",",C2,",",D2,",",E2)`